# problem with translate and replace methods

Tags: python

The goal of this program is to take n as an input Then get n words with meaning separated by whitespace and replace the word with meaning in Sentence And I try this But it's raise type error And with replace method returns the original sentence How can I fix this
Input
5
hello salam
goodbye khodafez
say goftan
we ma
you shoma
we say goodbye to you tonight
Output ma goftan khodafez to shoma tonight

```
n=int(input())
WordDict={}

for word in range(n) :
    word=input()
    Word=word.split()
    for i in range(2) :
        WordDict[Word[0]] = Word[1]

sentence=input()

words= WordDict.keys()
means=WordDict.values()

table=sentence.maketrans(words,means)
trans= sentence.translate(table)
print(trans)
```

Comment: Please provide an error trace

Comment: @matszwecja i get this error TypeError: maketrans() argument 2 must be str, not dict_values

Comment: Read what each of the arguments for maketrans() means. 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/maketrans